# Manipulating axes/display for line chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am fairly new to R and working on a practice case study to sharpen my skills. I'm running into issues with the line chart visualization for this data. I need to display monthly data, but I would like to change the monthly legend to show years instead of months for legibility. [A line chart consisting of one line charting proportion of deaths across each month over the course of 5 years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erpxd.png)

Here is the code I have:

```
#Imported libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Load the CSV file into monthly data frames and check the data
monthly <- read.csv('data/monthly_deaths.csv')
monthly

# Add a proportion_deaths column to the df, calculating the proportion of deaths per number of births for each month in monthly
monthly <- monthly %>% mutate(proportion_deaths = deaths / births)
monthly

# Create a ggplot line plot for the monthly proportion of deaths
monthly_plot <- ggplot(monthly, aes(x = date, y = proportion_deaths, group = 1)) +
             geom_line()
```

I've tried log scaling, changing the axis limits with and without clipping, scaling the date, mutating, lubridating; nothing seems to work. [image: A table containing dates in year-month-day format]

Comment: Please run `dput(head(monthly))` and paste the output into the body of your question. I suspect your `date` column is stored in character or factor format, not as dates, so ggplot2 is interpreting each month as a different category and labeling them all, instead of placing them on a continuum with occasional labels.

Comment: @csRstudy, the dupe links have several examples of how to get past this problem, though the theme is as JonSpring suggested: `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)` is a good start, then add `scale_x_date(...)` (look at its docs) to the `ggplot() + ... + ...` chain to change the axis ticks, labels-formatting, limits, etc. If that does not resolve your issue, please [edit] your question and provide more info as JonSpring suggested, then @-ping me and we can work through the differences, I'm happy to help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you both! I checked the dupe links, and found a solution. Perhaps I wasn't asking the right kind of question or using the right keywords in my initial search. The date column was a string instead of a date type, using mutate(date = as.Date(date)) solved the issue.